# Using getchar() to read from file

Tags: c, file, getchar

I have an assignment and basically i want to read all the bytes from an audio file using `getchar()` like this:
`while(ch = getchar()) != EOF)`
At some point I have to read 4 consecutive bytes that stand for *size of file* and I can't understand the following:
If the file my program is reading is for example 150 bytes in size, that is enough to be stored in 1 of the 4 bytes, which means that 3 of the bytes will be 0 and the last one will be 150 in that case. I understand that I need to read all 4 bytes, through 4 repetitions of the while in the above section of cod, in order to get all the information I need, but what exactly is getchar() going to return to my variable, as it returns the ASCII code for the character it just read?
Also what happens for larger numbers, that can't be stored in a single byte?

Comment: If a certain field of data in the file contains four bytes, you need to read all four bytes to get all the data. Even if the combined value of those four bytes could fit in a smaller type, the data in the file is still four bytes. Besides, you don't even *know* the value unless you actually read all four bytes and combine them in a suitable way.

Comment: Also be careful when using character-based functions to read arbitrary bytes. First of all remember that `getchar` returns an `int`. Then remember that a "character" of type `char` can be either `signed` *or* `unsigned`, and generally speaking when dealing with raw bytes (and not actual characters) you need to explicitly use unsigned types (i.e. `unsigned char`, or better yet `uint8_t`).

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And as mentioned, please learn how to **[edit]** your questions.

Comment: Have you covered things like arrays and/or what exactly comprises the bits of such variable types as `char` and `int`?  How about endiannness?  Because reading 4 values with `getchar()` and getting the correct combined value in all cases is actually difficult to do correctly.  And it also depends on how that data was written to the file - your teacher must have provided that information for you to be ensured of getting a correct result.

Comment: We have covered arrays but we are not allowed to use them in this assignment. The type of file I am trying to read is using little-endian. I am sorry that I didn't mention these information in the first place.

Comment: No, it doesn't return the ASCII code of anything. It returns an `int`. ASCII is an encoding standard, a mapping between a set of small integers and set of symbols. A binary file is not an ASCII-encoded text so it doesn't make sense to talk about ASCII in this context. The C standard doesn't specify ASCII or any other encoding anyway. If the file length is 150, then it is reasonable to assume that the 4 calls ro `getchar()` will return integers 150, 0, 0 and 0, in some order. You need to know which order it will be from the audio file format documentation.

Comment: It's the fact that we have only used `getchar()` in order to get the ASCII codes for what we put in the input up until this point, so I got confused. So about larger numbers, lets say I try a 1MB file, what is going to happen?

Comment: Again, ASCII is a standard for encoded **text**. Binary files are not text. ASCII is not relevant. For a 1 MB file, try to write how a 4-byte integer that represents this size would look like. Which byte values would it contain? Can you reconstruct the integer from its individual byte values, viewed as small integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cant comment since i dont have enough reputation, i am deeply perplexed with your question for I do not understand what do you mean or what are you trying to achieve
The function getChar() should be used for returning mostly a single byte at a time, in fact only upon reading your question did i check the manual to learn it reads more than one although from my experience and the tests i performed now it seems it is used for reading multi byte characters heres the simple code i used to check for it

```
    char * c;
    printf("Enter character: ");
    c = getchar();
    printf("%s",c);
```

The character i used and this will probably unformat is the stack overflow glyph i use in my polybar, 溜, here it shows as an asian character.

Not only that but fgets will return EOF when arriving at the end of the file(or when an error occurs) as stated in the linux manual
https://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar

Also upon further reading it depends on how the file stores data, if its big endian the first byte read will be 0,0,0,150 else if its  little endian it will be 150,0,0,0 but thats assuming it is reading 1 character at the time and not 4 at once as you described it

As for the "solution" of your question why not use fread() reading the 4 bytes at once or a derivative when it does it job properly?

EDIT
As asked by the comment the following "concatenates" the values bit-wise i used scanf because i was too lazy to manually check for every ASCII key, this assuming the file is big endian, ie 0,0,0,150 else invert the order in which the << is done and it should "just werk™"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
unsigned char c[4];
unsigned int dosomething(){
    unsigned int result=0;
    result= (unsigned int)c[0]<< 24 | (unsigned int)c[1]<< 16 | (unsigned int)c[2]<< 8 | (unsigned int)c[3];
    return result;
}
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter character: ");
        scanf ("%u", &c[i]);
        printf("%u\n", c[i]);
        //printf("%s",c);
    
    }
    printf("%u",dosomething());
    
  
    return 0;
}
```

Now for the fread it is used like the following fread(pointertodatatoread, sizeofdata, sizeofarray, filepointer);
for indepth look here is the manual:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fread.htm
this should be asked in a different thread as i feel im asking another question

Comment: The assignment is actually about using the getchar() ant putchar() functions properly.

Comment: @MantzouPitsou ive since edited my response after reading your question various times

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't read your edit. The file is little-endian and isn't getchar() used to read one byte at a time or am I mistaken?

Comment: well yes it is, the thing is that a character can occupy more than one byte thats why getchar() returns an int
glyphs and certain characters occupy more than a single byte
thats why fread would just solve that problem since you can tell it how many bytes can it read at once

Comment: I actually don't know how to use fread() but it seems to be very useful in this case, so I wish I could use it in this assignment. However in the case that I have a larger file (lets say 1MB for instance) the size of that would be stored in more than one bytes. So how could I read the whole thing using getchar )?

Comment: @MantzouPitsou i updated the answer as per your questions

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Comment: @MantzouPitsou could you upvote and accept my answer? plz?

Comment: No, @Imeguras, the reason that `getchar()` returns an `int` has **nothing whatever** to do with multibyte characters.  Its return value is always either `EOF` or in the range of `unsigned char`. When not `EOF`, that always represents a single byte read.  If you want to use it to read a multibyte character then you need one call for each byte.  `getchar()` cannot even distinguish character data (multibyte or otherwise) from non-character data

Comment: @JohnBollinger it worked for my double sized byte character

Comment: @Imeguras, the behavior of the standard library's `getchar()` is specified by [the C language standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.7).  Conforming implementations return an `int` that is either `EOF` or in the range of `unsigned char`.  If you think you observe different behavior then possibly you are using a different function, and possibly your implementation is nonconforming, but most probably you are simply mistaken.  A vast amount of code depends on `getchar()` to behave as specified, so a rogue implementation in that sense would be of little use.

Answer (score 1):

> If the file my program is reading is for example 150 bytes in size, that is enough to be stored in 1 of the 4 bytes, which means that 3 of the bytes will be 0 and the last one will be 150 in that case. I understand that I need to read all 4 bytes in order to get all the information I need, but what exactly is getchar() going to return to my variable, as it returns the ASCII code for the character it just read?

`getchar` doesn't know anything about ASCII.  It returns the numeric value of the byte it reads, or a special code, represented by `EOF`, if it cannot read a byte.  If you treat the byte as an ASCII code then that's a matter of *interpretation*.

Thus, if your file size is encoded as as three zero bytes followed by one byte with value 150, then `getchar()` will return that as 0, 0, 0, and 150 on four consecutive calls.